# How to use "loadingBody/loadingbody" template in angular p-treetable?

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am trying to use the following template with PrimeNG p-treetable in angular when data is loading.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="loadingbody" let-columns="columns">
  ...my Awesome code
</ng-template>
```

My whole code looks like this:

```
<p-treetable [loading]="true" ...other attributes>
   <ng-template pTemplate="headers" let-columns="columns">
      ...code for headers
   </ng-template>

   <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-columns="columns">
      ...code for body
   </ng-template>

   <ng-template pTemplate="loadingbody" let-columns="columns">
      ...my Awesome code
   </ng-template>

</p-treetable>
```

My "loadingbody" template is not firing even when the loading attribute is set to true.

The same code is working fine if I am using a regular table i.e "p-table".

Can anyone suggest the solution or (alternative if there is no solution) for this ?

Edit: I have also tried writing "loadingBody" instead of "loadingbody". Thanks
Edit: I have checked with the official doc, there is no option of "loadingbody" with treetable, Can anyone please suggest alternative ?

Comment: Did you checked the official documentation for the pre-table component that contains the "loadingbody" property or not?

Comment: @RebaiAhmed No the property "loadingbody" doesn't exist in treetable, it does with p-table. Can you suggest any alternative for this ?

Comment: I suggest to make it manually by using div or ng-container with conditional rendering loading body a boolean condition  maybe it helps